# How to solve this negative conditional probability problem?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

[image]

For #1a, I calculated **Pr(Cancer|Marker)** to be **0.03465**.

To solve #1b, I was going to try to use Baye's theorem through this expression:

**Pr(Cancer|No Marker)** = [Pr(No Marker|Cancer)*Pr(Cancer)]/Pr(No Marker)

However, I do not know what the value of Pr(No Marker|Cancer) is so I am not sure what to do next.

How would *you* go about solving #1b?

Comment: Hint: the text contains the probability  Pr(No Marker|Cancer)!!!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see what you mean. Would you mind submitting an answer and showing me what you're talking about?

Comment: You can easily relate the chance of "No Marker" to the chance of "Marker."

Comment: Yes. The chance of no marker is 0.8. But that still doesn't tell me the conditional probability of Cancer in No Marker people. So I'm not sure what you're getting at...

Comment: Similar rules hold for conditional probabilities.